# How does this site change the page without a link?

Tags: php, html

I have heard of HTML5 History but I do not think this is how the site works. As you can see, here is the site: https://www.bungie.net/en/Forums/Topics?pNumber=0&tSort=3&tType=0&d=undefined

When you click "All Topics" or anything on the left column of the forum, it'll show a loading animation then load the page. How was this achieved? If one was using PHP, what would be the best way to replicate this effect?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. It's all HTML and JS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: But can you submit/post through HTML5 History? Or would you just do it through Ajax?

Comment: If you want to dynamically generate the content then you will need a server-side language, like PHP, yes.

Comment: When "all topics" is clicked, It uses Ajax to make a new request to the server, then show the results.

Comment: @Pipe So it doesn't use HTML5 History?

Comment: it uses html5 history to change url, but not for content. Every URL change generate a new ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand this would be to use your web-inspector (Chrome Inspector [F12 Key], if you're using Google Chrome). Go to the '**Network**' Tab, and then click on "All Topics" on the web-page again, and you'll see a bunch of new stuff being added.

[image: Chrome Inspector]

Try clicking and exploring them, you'll learn where the request was sent to, the type of request: GET or POST, the response the server provided and the preview of the response, without any CSS of course.

That's about it, HTML5 history is not involved in what you witnessed, it's just a good old Ajax request being made.

Comment: Wouldn't HTML5 History have to be involved in order for it to change the address of the page?

Comment: Oh, yeah, If you need to manipulate the url as well, and add the previous url onto the browser history, you'll need to work with HTML5 History: Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API | https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/